# Converting a vector of maps to map of maps in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I've a vector of maps like this:

```
[{:categoryid 1, :categoryname "foo" } 
 {:categoryid 2, :categoryname "bar" } 
 {:categoryid 3, :categoryname "baz" }]
```

and would like to generate a map of maps like this for searching by categoryname

```
{"foo" {:categoryid 1, :categoryname "foo" }, 
 "bar" {:categoryid 2, :categoryname "bar" }, 
 "baz" {:categoryid 3, :categoryname "baz" }}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(reduce (fn [m {catname :categoryname :as input}]
          (assoc m catname input))
        {}
        [{:categoryid 1, :categoryname "foo" } 
         {:categoryid 2, :categoryname "bar" } 
         {:categoryid 3, :categoryname "baz" }])
```

Better yet,

```
(#(zipmap (map :categoryname %) %)
 [{:categoryid 1, :categoryname "foo" } 
  {:categoryid 2, :categoryname "bar" } 
  {:categoryid 3, :categoryname "baz" }])
```

Answer (score 16):

Another way: `(into {} (map (juxt :categoryname identity) [...]))`

Answer (score 1):

```
(ns code.groupby
  (:use clojure.contrib.seq-utils))


(def vector-of-maps [ {:categoryid 1, :categoryname "foo" }
                      {:categoryid 2, :categoryname "bar" }
                      {:categoryid 3, :categoryname "baz" } ])

(group-by :categoryname vector-of-maps)
```

Gives you a map of Vectors of maps

```
{"bar" [{:categoryid 2, :categoryname "bar"}],
 "baz" [{:categoryid 3, :categoryname "baz"}],
 "foo" [{:categoryid 1, :categoryname "foo"}]}
```

(which I now realise isn't what you wanted...sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it in Clojure, but in ClojureScript this variant appears to be faster than others:

```
(reduce #(assoc %1 (:categoryname %2) %2) {} [...])
```